# "This page wants to use speech" on android. How to disable it?

Tags: javascript, android, text-to-speech, responsivevoice

I am working on my text to speech app made in html css and javascript. It works on desktop and tablet or smartphone. It's made for people with intellectual disability. I use responsivevoice for the TTS.
When testing it in android tablet and smartphone, now I see the following on the bottom of the page each time when I want to use tts:
 "this page wants to use speech. Allow Deny"

[image]

Do you recognize this? Is there a way to change settings so that doesn’t show up again?

Here is a link to try it. Click on play. Not my site but I use this system.
So try it on android. Doesn't occur each time...
https://responsivevoice.org/

Comment: Maybe you could post a link so we could try it ourselves.

Comment: done after edit

Comment: I tried it on my browser (chrome android) and did not get the allow / deny, even when I blocked autoplay. My guess is that has something to do w/ autoplay, or "run plugins automatically" settings on some browsers. Unfortunately I think the details are going to vary by the device / browser.

Comment: ok. Now I found that on android, if in settings of firefox browser "Request Desktop Site" is checked: it doesn't show up but I really need this setting to be unchecked...

Comment: You aren't going to be able to twiddle the browser's settings without user interaction (which is a good thing). The best you can do is ask the user to change the setting. Or compile your own browser.

Comment: ok. But until a week ago, this didn't show up. Now it does on each android device. And no, I don't want to change browser settings with javascript. If I knew which setting to change, I could tell it to the people using my website. So they can change it if they want to. I prefer they can use the site as a normal android site and not as "Desktop site".

Answer (score 1):

Answer to my own question: I found that the warning comes from the script Responsivevoice. With the new version 1.5.5 and 1.5.6, this warning shows up. When I use the version 1.5.4, the warning doesn't show up. I received the following answer from ResponsiveVoice: "1.5.5 (and .6) begin dealing with a widespread issue on mobile phones, which is that TTS has to be triggered by a user gesture for security reasons (which often completely kills TTS). If 1.5.4 is working correctly for you, please use that in the meantime, we will get back to you as soon as we have news!"

Answer (score 0):

For me it stopped working with 1.5.7. Obviously older web engines (for me libwebkitgtk-3.0-0:amd64 version 2.4.11-0ubuntu0.1) will gradually require confirmation requests due to security.

Comment: I hope they will make the possibility to set this off so I can make a kind of alert by myself.